# What do "moosie" and "cheesebread" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The first time I went to testicular cancer, Bob the big moosie, the big cheesebread moved in on top of me in Remaining Men Together and started crying.

Source: Fight Club by Chuck Palahniuk

I didn't find the definitions of the words not in the Cambridge Dictionary not on the https://wordnik.com site.

I understand that "moosie" is some derivative from "moose". But I didn't see such an affix before and do not know what additional sense it adds. 
"Cheesebread" is obvious a concatenation of 2 words cheese and bread but I struggle to understand this metaphor too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that these aren't immediately understandable by a native speaker either. Palahniuk seems to like using unusual words and grammar to make his writing seem strange. I believe this is supposed to show the mental instability of the main character, but someone better acquainted with the novel could tell you more.

"-ie" or "-y" is an affix which creates diminutives, i.e. shorter and informal nouns. Sometimes it can be used on a noun X to mean "a certain thing related to X", but not always.

> food -> foodie *(one who enjoys food greatly)*
>
> communist -> commie
>
> self -> selfie *(a photo taken of oneself)*

So in this case, *moosie* is something like "informally mooselike person". Bob is obviously a big man, and probably a relatively docile one, as moose are herbivores.

*Cheesebread* is much harder; at first glance it calls to mind bread that has cheese in the middle. It is not easily apparent to a native speaker at all. [This site](https://sites.google.com/site/thefightclubnotes/bob) says that it relates to Bob having a metaphorically soft interior (cheese and bread are both soft). From what I gather Bob is rather feminized and the narrator seems to disdain this, so this would make sense. However, again, a reader of the novel could provide better context.

Comment: horse -> horsie

Comment: @eijen This is Bob: http://i.imgur.com/wwN07.jpg (found on http://screenplayhowto.com/beat-sheet/fight-club-beat-sheet/).

Comment: "cheese and bread are both soft".  That's a stretch. Most cheese is **not** soft in the middle.  But cheesebread (being bread) is. Cheesebread can be be different things; eg. bread with cheese on top, or bread with cheese baked into the middle. So I agree that the main interpretation is that Bob is a "big softie" (a gentle giant). And perhaps it also infers that he has a "cheese head" (not too smart).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native English speaker but in the context of this book I think you should link this with moose cheese, an expensive one...

Have you read the whole book? [spoiler alert!]

> When they are talking about human sacrifice?
> There is a store worker who drops out of school, working in 'a shit job' for just enough money to buy cheese and watch television.
> Bob is cheese for the Narrator, because Bob allows him to cry and therefore sleep.

Answer (score -1):

Cheesebread is heavy and full of calories, hence it's just another way of saying Bob's big and fat.  No hiddle meanings or references to "soft" need be inferred.